# differences between css and equivalent xpath in selenium 2.0

Tags: css, scala, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Still new to selenium and css/xpath locators. I stumbled across a problem where CSS works but the equivalent XPath doesn't, and I'd really like to know why. I'm using Scala in the examples but it's still the normal Java Selenium2 library. I also use the FirefoxDriver

Here's the interesting part of the HTML:

```
...
<li class="k-item k-filter-item k-state-default k-last" role="menuitem" style="z-index: auto;">
  ...
  <form class="k-filter-menu k-secondary">
    <div>
      <div class="k-filter-help-text">Show items with value that:</div>
      <span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" style="" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false">
      <span class="k-widget k-datetimepicker k-header" style="">
      <div>
        <button class="k-button" type="submit">Filter</button>
        <button class="k-button" type="reset">Clear</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</li>
...
```

I'm getting the **li** with

```
val filter = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.k-filter-item"))
```

which works for me.

Then, I want to find the button. It's a dynamic menu thingy sliding out and what not, so I need to wait for it to appear:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, selectorTimeout).until(
  new ExpectedCondition[Boolean] {
    override def apply(d: WebDriver) = {
      filter.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type=submit]")).isDisplayed
    }
  })
```

And that works nicely, too. My question is, why doesn't the xpath equivalent work:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, selectorTimeout).until(
  new ExpectedCondition[Boolean] {
    override def apply(d: WebDriver) = {
      filter.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).isDisplayed
    }
  })
```

Anybody?

**[EDIT]**
Selenium version: 2.35.0
FireFox driver: 2.35.0

I will try it with Opera now.

Comment: Any error did you get? Can you try `//button[contains(@type,'submit')]` ?

Comment: Wow. Have you tried it in any other browser than FF? This should definitely work. While it's obviously better to use CSS selector, I understand your confusion. This baffles me, too. Which Selenium version is this? And which Firefox? In firefox, both CSS selector and XPath support should be native. Huh.

Comment: You'll need the `.` in front of the XPath too I think: `.//button[@type='submit']`. Also try a more elaborate one: `.//descendant::button[@type='submit']`. (Not tested these, but it's a guess).

Comment: @Arran: you're right! Please turn your comment into an answer an I shall accept it!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the `.` in front of the XPath selector anyway, so that it'll search the current element's descendants/children:

```
.//button[@type='submit']
```

Sometimes, a more elaborate XPath can also help:

```
.//descendant::button[@type='submit']
```